# How to add dot with currency code in woocommerce plugin?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add a dot with currency code, for example, my currency code is RS then I want this format (RS.) then the amount will be displayed.
 I want this formate RS. 300 With my amount 300. kindly help me...

IN woocommerce I try many currency positions. for example in woocommerce they give us

- left
- right
- left with space
- right with space

But I also want "left with dot" and "right with dot".
how can I customize for this?

Answer (score 0):

Is this not the decimal seperator? Maybe add this to . and then set the number of decimals to whatever you need

Answer (score 0):

For This, You Must add a Custom Currency Symbol Try Adding bellow Code to your Functions.php in your child theme

```
/**
 * Custom currency and currency symbol
 */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_currencies', 'add_my_currency' );
function add_my_currency( $currencies ) {
 $currencies['Rs.'] = __( 'Pakistani Rupees', 'woocommerce' );
 return $currencies;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_currency_symbol', 'add_my_currency_symbol', 10, 2);
function add_my_currency_symbol( $currency_symbol, $currency ) {
 switch( $currency ) {
      case 'Rs.': $currency_symbol = 'Rs.'; break;
 }
 return $currency_symbol;
}
```